# gradle task order in command line

Tags: gradle, task

gradle task order in command line: e.g.,

```
gradle taskFoo taskBar
```

There is no order(or dependsOn) specified for taskFoo and taskBar in build.grade.

Will taskFoo be executed before taskBar as indicated by command line?

Gradle version: 5.4.1

Comment: Wouldn't it have been faster to just try it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Otherwise something like `gradle clean build` could not be used to rebuild.

First `taskFoo` and its dependencies will be executed, afterwards `taskBar` and its dependencies, as long as those later tasks were not already executed as a dependency, because every task can only be executed once in a build.